# LoaderManager does not see ContentProvider update

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-loadermanager

I am using a `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` to load data into a RecyclerView. The relationship works fine when  I `insert` a new entry to the contentProvider: The RecyclerView updates immediately. But if I `update` an existing entry, then I have t recreate the activity to see the changes. The code for update uses

```
 if (0 < count) {     getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null); }
```

just as the code for `insert`

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

So why would the LoaderManager see the insertions and not the updates?

**showing contentObserver**

I have never used this before so I am adding code to show how I am doing it.

I call

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(StuffContract.BASE_CONTENT_URI,
            true,
            new MyObserver(new Handler()));
```

where MyObserver is

```
class MyObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public MyObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        this.onChange(selfChange, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

**update**

Note: everything here works fine. inserts work, updates work. The only problem is that the CursorLoader does not detect dynamic updates. I know the updates do happen dynamically as I am logging the updates. So the **only** problem is that updates don't propagate to the CursorLoader unless I restart

```
package com.company.android.model.contentprovider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.company.android.utils.CompanyLogger;


public class DogTreatProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String TAG = DogTreatProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    private DogTreatDBHelper mOpenHelper;

    static final int DOG_TREAT_ALL = 100;//group
    static final int DOG_TREAT_BY_ID = 200;//single
    static final int DOG_TREAT_BY_DAY = 300;//group

    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        sUriMatcher.addURI(DogTreatContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, DogTreatContract.PATH_DOG_TREAT, DOG_TREAT_ALL);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(DogTreatContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, DogTreatContract.PATH_DOG_TREAT + "/#", DOG_TREAT_BY_ID);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(DogTreatContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, DogTreatContract.PATH_DOG_TREAT + "/"
                + DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.PATH_SUBSET + "/#/#", DOG_TREAT_BY_DAY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return false;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case DOG_TREAT_ALL:
                return DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.CONTENT_TYPE;
            case DOG_TREAT_BY_DAY:
                return DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.CONTENT_TYPE + DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.PATH_SUBSET;
            case DOG_TREAT_BY_ID:
                return DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.CONTENT_ITEM_BASE_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unkown uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        CompanyLogger.d(TAG, "query reached for: %s", uri.toString());
        Cursor retCursor = null;
        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case DOG_TREAT_ALL:
                retCursor = getAllDogTreats(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                break;
            case DOG_TREAT_BY_DAY:
                CompanyLogger.d(TAG, "uri matched successfuly for DOG_TREAT_BY_DAY ");
                retCursor = getDogTreatsForDay(uri, projection);
                break;
            case DOG_TREAT_BY_ID:
                retCursor = getDogTreatById(uri, projection);
        }
        if (null != retCursor) {
            retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        }
        return retCursor;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        CompanyLogger.d(TAG, "single insert called");
        if (null == mOpenHelper) {
            mOpenHelper = new DogTreatDBHelper(getContext());
        }
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final long id = db.insert(DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Uri retUri;
        if (0 < id) {
            retUri = DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.buildDogTreatUri(id);
            CompanyLogger.d(TAG, "insertion returns uri %s", uri);
        } else {
            throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return retUri;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        CompanyLogger.d(TAG, "delete");
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        if (null == mOpenHelper) {
            mOpenHelper = new DogTreatDBHelper(getContext());
        }
        final String idSelection = DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry._ID + " = ? ";
        final long ID = DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.getDogTreatIdFromUri(uri);
        final String[] idSelectionArgs = {Long.toString(ID)};
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int count = db.update(DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, idSelection, idSelectionArgs);
        if (0 < count) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            CompanyLogger.d(TAG, "updating some data with uri %s", uri);
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(11)
    public void shutdown() {
        if (null != mOpenHelper) {
            mOpenHelper.close();
        }
        super.shutdown();
    }

    private Cursor getAllDogTreats(Uri uri, final String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        CompanyLogger.d(TAG, "Call to get all getAllDogTreats");
        if (null == mOpenHelper) {
            mOpenHelper = new DogTreatDBHelper(getContext());
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.query(DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
//        return db.query(DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    private Cursor getDogTreatsForDay(Uri uri, final String[] projection) {
        CompanyLogger.d(TAG, "getDogTreatsForDay");
        if (null == mOpenHelper) {
            mOpenHelper = new DogTreatDBHelper(getContext());
        }
        final String startTimeColumn = DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.COLUMN_START_TIME;
        final String selection = "? <= " + startTimeColumn + " AND " + startTimeColumn + " <= ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.getStartAndEndDateFromUri(uri);
        final String sortOrder = startTimeColumn + " ASC";
        SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.query(DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    }

    private Cursor getDogTreatById(Uri uri, final String[] projection) {
        if (null == mOpenHelper) {
            mOpenHelper = new DogTreatDBHelper(getContext());
        }
        final String selection = DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry._ID + " = ? ";
        final long ID = DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.getDogTreatIdFromUri(uri);
        final String[] selectionArgs = {Long.toString(ID)};
        SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.query(DogTreatContract.DogTreatEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

**LOGGING**

```
02-17 08:19:41.386 29422-29422/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
02-17 08:19:41.386 29422-29422/? E/Zygote: v2
02-17 08:19:41.386 29422-29422/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10465
02-17 08:19:41.386 29422-29422/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
02-17 08:19:41.386 29422-29422/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G900T_5.1.1 ver=38
02-17 08:19:41.386 29422-29422/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G900T_5.1.1_0038
02-17 08:19:41.396 29422-29422/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
02-17 08:19:41.396 29422-29422/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-17 08:19:41.416 29422-29422/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
02-17 08:19:41.416 29422-29422/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
02-17 08:19:41.496 29422-29422/com.company.company D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
02-17 08:19:41.536 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
02-17 08:19:41.536 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
02-17 08:19:41.956 29422-29422/com.company.company D/MainActivity: LoaderManager: onCreateLoader timestamp: 1455696000000
02-17 08:19:41.966 29422-29422/com.company.company D/MainActivity: LoaderManager: loader created for uri: content://com.company.android/dogTreat/subset/1455696000000/1455782399999
02-17 08:19:41.966 29422-29509/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: query reached for: content://com.company.android/dogTreat/subset/1455696000000/1455782399999
02-17 08:19:41.966 29422-29509/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: uri matched successfuly for DOG_TREAT_BY_DAY 
02-17 08:19:41.966 29422-29509/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: getdogTreatsForDay
02-17 08:19:41.976 29422-29510/com.company.company D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-17 08:19:41.986 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
02-17 08:19:41.986 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
02-17 08:19:42.016 29422-29422/com.company.company D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
02-17 08:19:42.016 29422-29510/com.company.company I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                 OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
                                                                 Build Date: 05/29/15 Fri
                                                                 Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.029
                                                                 Remote Branch: 
                                                                 Local Patches: 
                                                                 Reconstruct Branch: 
02-17 08:19:42.016 29422-29510/com.company.company I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-17 08:19:42.036 29422-29510/com.company.company D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096
02-17 08:19:42.036 29422-29510/com.company.company D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-17 08:19:42.096 29422-29422/com.company.company D/MainActivity: call to onLoadFinished LoaderManager
02-17 08:19:42.096 29422-29422/com.company.company D/MainActivity: LoaderManager: onLoadFinished with count: 0
02-17 08:19:42.136 29422-29422/com.company.company I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1ffc12d0 time:71901647
02-17 08:19:44.056 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:19:44.296 29422-29422/com.company.company D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-17 08:19:44.316 29422-29422/com.company.company D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-17 08:19:44.346 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
02-17 08:19:44.346 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
02-17 08:19:44.386 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
02-17 08:19:44.386 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
02-17 08:19:44.436 29422-29422/com.company.company D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
02-17 08:19:44.516 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ListView: change accessibility focus position = 1392
02-17 08:19:46.766 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:19:47.536 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:19:47.696 29422-29422/com.company.company D/MainActivity: LoaderManager: onCreateLoader timestamp: 1455782400000
02-17 08:19:47.696 29422-29422/com.company.company D/MainActivity: LoaderManager: loader created for uri: content://com.company.android/dogTreat/subset/1455782400000/1455868799999
02-17 08:19:47.706 29422-29721/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: query reached for: content://com.company.android/dogTreat/subset/1455782400000/1455868799999
02-17 08:19:47.706 29422-29721/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: uri matched successfuly for DOG_TREAT_BY_DAY 
02-17 08:19:47.706 29422-29721/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: getdogTreatsForDay
02-17 08:19:47.736 29422-29422/com.company.company D/MainActivity: call to onLoadFinished LoaderManager
02-17 08:19:47.736 29422-29422/com.company.company D/MainActivity: LoaderManager: onLoadFinished with count: 0
02-17 08:19:47.736 29422-29422/com.company.company E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-17 08:19:51.436 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:19:51.616 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
02-17 08:19:51.616 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
02-17 08:19:51.626 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
02-17 08:19:51.626 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
02-17 08:19:51.666 29422-29422/com.company.company D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
02-17 08:19:54.236 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:19:54.446 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
02-17 08:19:54.446 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
02-17 08:19:54.476 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
02-17 08:19:54.476 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
02-17 08:19:54.506 29422-29422/com.company.company D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
02-17 08:19:57.186 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:19:57.366 29422-29422/com.company.company E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-17 08:19:58.176 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:20:04.876 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:20:05.026 29422-29422/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: single insert called
02-17 08:20:05.046 29422-29422/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: insertion returns uri content://com.company.android/dogTreat
02-17 08:20:05.046 29422-29422/com.company.company D/DBPojoTransducer: insert dogTreat into content://com.company.android/dogTreat/13
02-17 08:20:05.076 29422-29422/com.company.company E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-17 08:20:05.076 29422-30030/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: query reached for: content://com.company.android/dogTreat/subset/1455782400000/1455868799999
02-17 08:20:05.076 29422-30030/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: uri matched successfuly for DOG_TREAT_BY_DAY 
02-17 08:20:05.086 29422-30030/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: getdogTreatsForDay
02-17 08:20:05.086 29422-29422/com.company.company D/MainActivity: call to onLoadFinished LoaderManager
02-17 08:20:05.086 29422-29422/com.company.company D/MainActivity: LoaderManager: onLoadFinished with count: 1
02-17 08:20:05.126 29422-29422/com.company.company D/TimeUtils: Date 2016-02-18T08:19:00.000-08:00
02-17 08:20:16.496 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:20:17.046 29422-29422/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: query reached for: content://com.company.android/dogTreat/13
02-17 08:20:17.046 29422-29422/com.company.company D/dogTreatContract: uri.getPathSegments(): [dogTreat, 13]
02-17 08:20:17.066 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
02-17 08:20:17.066 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
02-17 08:20:17.066 29422-29422/com.company.company D/AddTreatFragment: dogTreat.getTreatType().name(): BREAKFAST
02-17 08:20:17.066 29422-29422/com.company.company D/TimeUtils: Date 2016-02-18T08:19:00.000-08:00
02-17 08:20:17.076 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
02-17 08:20:17.076 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
02-17 08:20:17.106 29422-29422/com.company.company D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
02-17 08:20:19.186 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:20:19.386 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
02-17 08:20:19.386 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
02-17 08:20:19.416 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
02-17 08:20:19.416 29422-29422/com.company.company D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
02-17 08:20:19.436 29422-29422/com.company.company D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
02-17 08:20:20.586 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:20:22.076 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:20:22.296 29422-29422/com.company.company E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-17 08:20:23.996 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:20:24.116 29422-29422/com.company.company D/Editor: isTwoFingerGestureRecognitionEnabled1
02-17 08:20:24.126 29422-29422/com.company.company D/Editor: isTwoFingerGestureRecognitionEnabled1else
02-17 08:20:24.156 29422-29422/com.company.company D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
02-17 08:20:30.666 29422-29422/com.company.company D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-17 08:20:30.816 29422-29422/com.company.company D/dogTreatContract: uri.getPathSegments(): [dogTreat, 13]
02-17 08:20:30.836 29422-29422/com.company.company D/dogTreatProvider: updating some data with uri content://com.company.android/dogTreat/13
02-17 08:20:30.836 29422-29422/com.company.company D/DBPojoTransducer: update of dogTreat affected 1 entry
02-17 08:20:30.866 29422-29422/com.company.company E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Comment: is `notifyChange` really called in both cases? with what `uri`?

Comment: `db.update` returns a count so naturally I am calling `notifyChange` on the very same uri that I came in with. But in the case of `insert` `db.insert` does return a uri so I call `notifyChange` on that returned uri. But the root is still the same. The only difference is the id.

Comment: tried for testing to call `ContentResolver#registerContentObserver` with some `Log.d` inside the observer?

Comment: Where should I put that call? I have never used `registerContentObserver` before as I always use loaders.

Comment: anywhere in your `Activity#onCreate`

Comment: I have updated to show what I am doing. Am I using it correctly? I am seeing no change. I have never used this class before.

Comment: add `Log.d` inside `onChange` to log `uri` value and watch the `logcat`

Comment: For both update and insert I see the uri in onChange. It's the same uri except for it is followed by `/6` which simply represents the dbId of the row I am updating. So based on that it looks like the same uri is being called.

Comment: so you have the proof that `notifyChange` does work in your provider, now you can delete the testing `MyObserver` stuff and debug your loader's code

Comment: But what would cause a loader to observe insertions and not updates? I am using a typical loader where I query for data from a content provider. And also, if I rotate or relaunch the app, the updates appear; they just don't show up immediately (i.e. for the same session) the way the inserts do.

Comment: Actually I forgot to say thanks: I just learn how to use registerContentObserver. So thanks!

Comment: add some `Log.d` inside `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` methods and watch the `logcat`, also add `Log.d` inside `insert` and `update` methods to make sure they are called

Comment: Not one of the methods is called for `update` but all of them are called for `insert`.

Comment: I can attest that the data in the database is changed for the update. It is simply not changed in the adapter, i.e. it does not reach the loader somehow.

Comment: are you using `CursorLoader` ? what if you use some existing content provider? for example contacts provider and update some contacts?

Comment: I am using `implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` on my activity

Comment: are you using `CursorLoader` or some custom `Loader<Cursor>`?

Comment: I am using CursorLoader. I just noticed it.

Comment: so for testing use the existing content provider, for example contacts provider and update some contacts?

Comment: I figure how to do the test without breaking my code. So the contact stuff work fine. It works when I add contacts and it works when I edit contacts.

Comment: Post your provider code

Comment: I have posted the provider class

Comment: and add some logcat (or wherever `CompanyLogger` prints out)

Comment: I don't understand. You want to see the log messages that I see? Which ones? You want to see what prints out when I update and when I insert?

Comment: everything, including `query`

Comment: you are updating `content://com.company.android/dogTreat/13` but no loader was created for such uri (or parent like `content://com.company.android/dogTreat/`)

Comment: Thanks for helping me resolve this issue. Without a check mark, people in need may not know that this question is answered. So will you please post as a response that we may show indication to others? Thanks.

Comment: sure, but i have no idea what solved your problem

Comment: I force use `content://com.company.android/dogTreat` everywhere I need notification.